# Full Width Product Image

Tags: theme

I have updated our website page layout so that the main product image is 12 columns width at the top of the page, but the site seems to still force the images to be 363px wide. The site theme is Ultimo.
Where do I find the setting for this image size please as I've looked through the configuration and can't see it:

http://www.forefrontcases.co.uk/apple-ipad-mini-with-retina-display-purple-clam-shell-leather-case

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your image size is not large.. its just 363*363

Comment: Not adding this as an answer cause I am not familiar with the Ultimo theme, but your image is being resized to 363px (inspect the path of the image). Check out the theme options to see if this is set anywhere, or dig into the code. The default template file is `template/catalog/product/media.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your image size from backend suppose that your theme fetch image size from configuration

Login to admin panel

go to `system->configuration->catalog->catalog->product Image`.

you can configure your product image size from there and set product image size for product view page as well product list page.

Comment: Thank you. This option doesn't exist in our installation, but I believe it might be because it's an older version of Magento that needs updating. The only image option I have is to set the placeholder for each image instance.

Comment: @BenYates I think this option avliable in magento1.9

Comment: @BenYates for change image diention you can check `yourMagentoRoot/ap/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`  file and check for resize method and change resize value

Comment: We are using 1.7 so it's a bit dated sorry. I have found this file: app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/infortis/cloudzoom/product/view/media.phtml and have commented out the resize value, but now the product image sits at the left of the window.

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 2 you can get the config file at **/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/etc/view.xml**